# how to remove focused effect from a selector

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

/*Am implementing a dialog box where list and some message is displaying-  In left key I removed the current focus using blur.And highlighting the message area"wizard_subtext"  */

```
        handleDialogLEFT : function(){
        this.Wizard.Wizardlist.blur();
        $(".wizard_subText").attr('tabindex', 1).focus();
        $('.wizard_subText').css({
            color: 'white',
            background: '#4C4C4C'

        });
        }
```

/*My doubt is , how to delete these css changes when am giving control back to list View
I don't want to hide the subtext element, but it should change to its origial text and background color
 */

```
        handleDialogRIGHT: function(){

        this.vodWizard.Wizardlist.focus();



     }
```

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do: ` if($(".wizard_subText").attr('tabindex',-1).focus())` ??? To set style, you should just use a class which can be toggled

Comment: handle dialogleft function is working correctly.., here am changing the backgraound colour for selector".wizard_subtext".. but my doubt comes when am giving focus back to list element , in my case its is Wizardlist.focus(), So how to remove the css property of "wizard_subtext" that i hv set previously

Comment: like i said, use a class to set style. Add/remove this class when needed. BTW, you could just set it using only CSS3 with :focus pseudo class

Comment: use of `attr()` is wrong if you have more than one `$(".wizard_subText")` in page...please explain in detail the behavior expected